# Alternative definitions of mean curvature flow

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

I am reading the mean curvature flow from a thesis. Here, the mean curvature flow is defined as follows:

Let $(M,\varphi_0)$ be an hypersurface. Given $T>0$, the geometric mean curvature flow of $(M,\varphi_0)$, up to $T$, is a family of smooth immersions $\varphi: M\times [0,T)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ that satifies

[image]

where $H(p,t)$ and $\nu(p,t)$ are respectively the mean curvature and the unit normal of the hypersurface $(M,\varphi_t)$ where $\varphi_t(p)=\varphi(p,t)$.

Later, is said that the above definition is equivalent to a family of smooth vector field $ X:M\times [0,T)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ with $X(p,t)\in d\varphi_t(T_pM)$ such that

[image]

Actually I can not understand why.

Comment: Hello, can I have the title of the thesis you are talking about? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direction of the flow at $(p,t)$ is $\partial_t\phi(p,t)=:V$, a vector in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ — or in a suitable tangent space if you have your flow live on a manifold.
This vector can be split in two components, one normal to the surface $M_t=\phi(M,t)$ and another one tangent to it.
The first formulation says that the normal component of $V$ has size $H$.
The second formulation says that the full vector $V$ is $H\nu+X$, where $X$ is tangent to $M_t$.
The normal component of $H\nu+X$ has size $H$, so the two descriptions of $V$ are equivalent.

If you are interested in tracking the movement of the surface as a set, then the normal component of $V$ is sufficient information to describe everything.
If you want to track the movement of individual points on $M$ in time, then you also need to know the component of motion along the surface.

I hope this illustrates why the two descriptions are equivalent and why you might want to use both.

Comment: I got it. Thank you!

Comment: Hello, can you expand on $M_t$ a little more, please? Why don't we consider $M$ with a time-dependent metric $\varphi_t^*\eta$, where $\eta$ is the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$? With this consideration, can we define a second fundamental form to compare the geometry of $M$ with that of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$?

Comment: @Wombat Please ask a separate question if you have follow-up questions. If this answer needs clarification, I can do that, but that doesn't seem to be what you're after. (In short: $M_t$ is a time-dependent hypersurface and you can do all kinds of things with it. To decide whether you should do something you can do depends on what you're trying to achieve.)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Thank you. I did ask this question in another post (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4796729/second-fundamental-form-of-m-for-an-immersion-fm-ton-barg-to-be-consid), but with the general case of  $\varphi: M\times [0,T)\to(N,g)$. What I want to do with this case is learn to define the second fundamental form and then derive the evolution equation of the induced metric.